# regex - remove string between delimiters

Tags: python, regex

I have this string

```
test_script_20180308.csv  
test_script_32343_121655_20180308_report.csv
```

I am able to truncate the string after `'_2018'` using `split()` resulting in `'test_script'` and `'test_script_32343_121655'`

Having difficulty as to how to implement it using `re.sub()`. Any thoughts?
Also, how how can I trim `'test_script_32343_121655_20180308_report.csv'` to `'test_script_32343_121655_report.csv'` where `'20180308'` is a dynamic date?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you want the first one to become? (`test_script_20180308.csv`)

Comment: @SeanBreckenridge how to use re.sub() from `test_script_20180308.csv` to `test_script`

Comment: With just these examples, the trivial `re.sub(r'_2018.*', '', string)` does what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why you need Regex for this. Simple `str.split` and `str.join` should do:

```
In [22]: str_ = 'test_script_32343_121655_20180308_report.csv'

# splitting on `_`
In [23]: splt = str_.split('_')

# joining the needed list elements with `_`
In [24]: '_'.join(splt[:4] + splt[5:])
Out[24]: 'test_script_32343_121655_report.csv'
```

If you insist on Regex:

```
# match `_` followed by digits, with a positive lookahead
# to match `_` followed by a non-digit character
In [25]: re.sub(r'_\d+(?=_[^\d])', '', str_)
Out[25]: 'test_script_32343_121655_report.csv'
```